# Translating ministerial job title

Tags: translation, meaning

[image]

I need help understanding this title.

國家 in this case is China. 
部委 are ministries and commissions 
某司： a certain department (of the above)
項目：project 
處長：head （of department）

But why is there a second 處 and is he head of only one project in the department?

Comment: 项目处 project center (department/office) + 处长 director —— so he’d be in charge of all projects in the department

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used the hong kong police force as an example:

https://www.police.gov.hk/ppp_tc/01_about_us/os_chart.html

commissioner of police --> 警務處處長

Deputy Commissioner of Police --> 警務處副處長

commissioner is the #1 of the police force, deputy commissioner is the #2;
in chinese, these're 處長 & 副處長.

then, the term "police" is translated to 警務處, that's why there're two 處 in a short title, one is from the department name, the second is from the job title.

now, the trickiest one, there're 5 "departments" (divisions) in the police force, which is also translated to "處":

director of operations a department --> 行動處處長

so, if we put together "director of operations of hong kong police (force)", we could get 香港警務處行動處處長, that 3 "處" in the title.

fortunately, it's acceptable to translate "police force" to "警隊", that the above title is 香港警隊行動處處長.

back to your question, i think he's a project manager, or the head of projects, in particular government department.

have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

项目处处长 means 项目处**的**处长, he is a 处长 of a 项目处. Similarly, 某村村长, 某局局长.

Mainland

Here is a structure images.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Very easy to understand:

The structure of current State Council is

General Office > 
Cabinet-level Department Constituting the State Council (Ministries)部/委 + Special Organization -> 
Department 司 
-> Division 处 
-> Section 科

"国家部委某司项目处处长"

"国家部委某司" here refer it's an anonymous department of an anonymous ministry of PRC. But according to the plot, it's easy to tell it's either Ministry of Land and Resource or Ministry of Housing and Urban-Rural Development.

"项目处" here refer the Project Division. "项目处" is the name of that Division. Probably using a faking name.

"项目处处长” here refer the head of Project Division.

And the Department-Divison-Section relationship could be applied to the most organization of China.

That's a good show btw.